# Proving power series $\sum a_n (x-a)^n$ converges uniformly on every compact subset of $(a-R, a+R)$ where $R$ is the radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, compactness

Note that $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ for all n and $a\in  \mathbb{R}$ as well.

---

Here's my attempt:

Let $S$ be a compact subset of $(a-R,a+R)$. Let $r:= \max \{|a-\inf S|, |a-\sup S|\} $. Since $\inf S \in S$, $|\inf S - a| <R$ and likewise $|\sup S - a|<R$. It is also clear that $\sum a_n r^n$ converges absolutely.

Now, let $x\in S$. It is easy to show that $|x-a|\le r.$ Now, for $n>m$, we have that $|a_m(x-a)^m + \ldots+a_n(x-a)^n|\le |a_mr^m|+\ldots+|a_nr^n|$. The right hand side of the inequality can be made arbitrarily small because $\sum a_n r^n$ converges absolutely. This completes the proof.

---

Is this proof correct? Alternative proofs are welcome.

Comment: You need to prove *uniform* convergence, right? The word is missing from the title.

Comment: (Anyway, the result is easy, as your argument shows, once one knows that series converge absolutely within their interval of convergence. All you say about this is that it is "clear".)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Yes. Thanks for pointing that out.